# Infopath 2013 - Changing a text box from single line to multi-line in a SharePoint form

Tags: forms, sharepoint, infopath

I'm currently working on building a SharePoint form in InfoPath 2013 and I've run into some trouble. I've created a text box in a section to allow users to enter comments but they only have the ability to create single line comments. I need this text box to allow multi-line comments but when I attempt to make this change in the text box properties provided by InfoPath, it annoyingly also checks and grays-out the read-only option. What good is a multi-line text box that is set to read-only? I'm not opposed to changing it in the XML document that InfoPath pulls the data fields from, but I've not been able to make the change and have InfoPath play nicely with the XML file. If you guys have any info that would allow me to finish this form, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround I use frequently. First you have to prepare **unbound** text control on the form. Set it as multi-line and leave read-only box unchecked. Copy this control into section with secondary data connection controls. Now change binding of this control to the field from the secondary data connection and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath requires any multiline textbox bound to a secondary data source field to be read-only. I don't know why, but I can only presume that there is some design consideration there.

This limitation doesn't apply to fields that are in the main data source. So if you would like to allow users to edit multiline text, you can copy the value to a field in your main data source, show that field in your view, and then copy the value back as needed when you need to resubmit the data.